# Не могу подключить Boost на MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, codeblocks

Привет!
Я пытался установить Boost на свой комп с помощью MinGW.
Я следовал [этой инструкции](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs18dmVDhiM).
Но на шаге, когда надо писать следующее :

```
b2.exe toolset=gcc
```

я получаю ошибки.
Я приложил также скриншот своей cmd.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что не так? Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо. А чтобы поставить новый - нужно удалить старый и впихнуть на его место?<br>P.s. я не смог установить этот компилятор nuwen. :( Мои действия : удалил старый MinGW, который шел вместе с codeblocks, закинул nuwen. Появились ошибки связаные с тем, что настройки codeblocks требовали файлы, которых в этом nuwen нет. Я закинул с предыдущего minGW эти файлы. Все правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Сборка для MinGW:

1) Скачать исходники Boost, распаковать куда хочется.

2) Скачать MinGW.

3) Создать файл env.bat* следующего содержания (он должен храниться в папке <путь к папке компилятора>\bin):

```
    REM SETTING UP MINGW-W64 ENVIRONMENT
    SET PATH=%PATH%;<путь к папке компилятора>\bin;
```

*этот файлик настраивает переменные среды

4) Создать ярлык для env.bat и поместить на рабочий стол. В свойствах ярлыка подправить путь к объекту следующим образом:

```
    C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /A /Q /K <путь к env.bat>
```

После этих 4 махинаций можно просто кликать по ярлыку на рабочем столе.

5) Запустив ярлык, переходите в открывшейся консоле в папку с распакованными исходниками Boost:

```
    CD /D "<путь к исходникам>"
```

6) Ввести:

```
    bootstrap.bat gcc
```

Да, именно опция gcc отвечает и за GCC, и за MinGW. Производится процесс сборки Boost.Build Engine.

7) Ввести:

```
    b2 toolset=gcc
```

Производится процесс сборки самого Boost. Ждать.

Comment: Я такое уже пробовал. Когда запускал cmd - там писало, что-то типа REM не является командой.

Comment: какая версия MinGW? Попробуйте последнюю версию MinGW-w64. С ней буст собрался очень даже корректно.

Comment: Ссылочка не найдется?

Comment: Предварительно удалите вообще Code::Blocks на время. Потом установите отдельно вот этот [компилятор](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/win-builds).